# Label image as table in LaTeX

Tags: tables, graphics, floats, labels

Complicated tables need to be included in my thesis, but it is easier to put images of them obtained through scanning from a book.  Can I insert an image, but have it count as a table?

One approach I thought of to achieve this would be to make a 1x1 table and put a figure in the cell. Are there any other ways to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can put everything you want into a `table` environment, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \includegraphics{example-image}
  \caption{This is a table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: picture used as table]

Answer (score 1):

You asn also call `capt-of` package into service.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,capt-of}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{exapmple-image}
\captionof{table}{Table caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `capt-of` is meant to use a `\caption` outside of a float. Your solution to this particular problem doesn't seem like a good idea, as a `figure` can overtake a `table` but in this example your `figure`-type float doesn't contain a figure and you don't want it to overtake a `table`.